# Random variable generation with a specific mass function in Matlab

Tags: matlab, random, probability

I must write a computer program that, when given a probability mass function
{pj , j = 1, . . . , n} as an input, gives as an output the value of a random
variable having this mass function. Those are my only informations about the problem. i tried this

```
%f(x)=pdf 
%F(x)=cdf 
%X=tixaia metavliti 

f(x);
X;
F(x)= cumsum(f(x));

%firstly we want F(x) to have unique values
%we remove the non-unique values from cdf and X
[F(x),mask] = unique(F(x));
X = X(mask);

%apply inverse interpolation
%so we can produce random value X from the cdf

u = rand;

projection = interp1( F(x),X,u );
```

is that code any near to the solution of my problem? Can anyone help me?

Comment: Trying to clarify what you mean; you are given an arbitrary pmf, and asked to sample N datapoints from it (without replacement), effectively producing a random sample of N observations conforming to that pmf?

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou yes, exactly that. I never used Malab before and i'm not very familiar with it. Can you help me somehow?

Comment: Asking for people to write code for you tends to be frowned upon in SO (not criticizing, that's just how it is). But here's a starting point: http://matlabtricks.com/post-44/generate-random-numbers-with-a-given-distribution   Try to understand the 'technique' of getting a cumulative distribution function and an inverse transform from that first. Then try to write your own code. If you have problems with specific code _you_ wrote, the SO community is usually happy to help at that point.

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou Σ'ευχαριστώ πολύ,i will study the link and try to apply it.!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example that samples 2 values from the vector (7 8 9 10) based on the probabilities defined. It uses the statistical toolbox.

```
    R = randsample([7 8 9 10],2,true,[0.15 0.35 0.35 0.15])
```

If you want to code it yourself, Tasos pointed you to right link.